# ASP.NET controller data annotation validation: Class-level validation attribute called as if property-level

Tags: asp.net, validation, data-annotations

I have something roughly equivalent to the following code. A `POST`ed  query object, that contains a sub-object with some details, and some custom validation code to glue the validation of the sub-object to the query object. The sub-object has a validation property on the class-level, which is causing the problem:

```cs
class Query : IValidatableObject
{
  [Required]
  public Filter? FilterField { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
  {
    var list = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(
      FilterField,
      new ValidationContext(FilterField) {
        MemberName = nameof(FilterField)
      },
      list,
      validateAllProperties: true);
    return list;
  }
}

[IsAnInt(Name = nameof(MyProp))]
class Filter {
  public int MyProp { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class IsAnIntAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  public string Name { get; init; }

  protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    if (validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(Name).GetValue(value) is not int)
      return new ValidationResult("not int!", new[] { Name });
    else
      return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

Now, when `Query` is validated, upon entry into the `IsAnIntAttribute.IsValid` method, I would expect `validationContext.ObjectType` to be `typeof(Filter)`.

Stepping through the code in my debugger, I find that this is indeed the case in my test suite where I use `Validator.TryValidateObject` on a `Query`. The `Query.Validate` method is called, and it passes the `Filter` instance to the `ValidationContext` constructor.

Things then break down, however, when I use the `Query` object as an argument to a controller action:

```cs
[ApiController]
class QueryableController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost("")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessQuery([FromBody] Query query)
  {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
    return NoContent();
  }
}
```

When I make a `POST` request to this endpoint, and step through `IsAnIntAttribute.IsValid` with my debugger, I find that the `validationContext.ObjectInstance` is set to the parent `Query` and thus `validationContext.ObjectType` is `typeof(Query)` and the method exits with a `NullReferenceException`.

What is going on? Do ASP.net controllers use a different validation call than `Validator.TryValidateObject`? It seems almost like it makes a call to `Validator.TryValidateProperty`?

If so, why? Can it be changed? Should I change my code to account for this?